# javascript window.onload: i have to reload the page

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

i've writed this code in my google tag manger account:

```
<script>
window.onload=function myfunction(){document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "some text with <a href=#>link</a>";}
</script>
```

the purpose is to change the node text when all the page is loaded.
The problem is that is not working properly.
The tag is fired correctly but when i load the page the text doesnt change. Only if i reload the page again, things work correctly.
How can i solve? Thanks in advance

Comment: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { /* ... */ })`

Comment: `window.onload=function() { ... }`

Comment: @Jack — Making the function anonymous won't make a difference. Using a named function expression there is fine.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code please, specifically the piece of HTML with the tag `id`.

Comment: As per your question you create an onload handler when the page is all loaded. It is quite possible that is does not fire because the page has already loaded - if you fire at gtm.load that is already equivalent to window.onload, you do not need to (and quite possibly should not) repeat that in you JS code.

Comment: hi i've tried the solution by noisypixy but didnt work. @EikePierstorff: i dont completely understand what you mean. how would you write the code.